# ‘…funding {on/in/for} a small number of departments’

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

"Funding on" versus "funding in" versus "funding for"? Which of the three is correct.

E.g.

> The government concentrates research funding **on/in/for** a small number of top departments.

Comment: You need to supply a sentence, all three are valid.

Comment: Please share an example.

Comment: @Mari-LouA please see the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonBassford please check the updated question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the specific sentence you added, either *on* or *in* would work.

Answer (score 1):

Does an agency concentrate/focus/direct funding **on**, **in**, or **for** a department?

I believe that all three prepositions are acceptable, there's really not much difference in meaning. In the OP's case, I'd suggest using the preposition "in"

“… *funding* ***in a*** [small] ***number of*** [top] ***departments***”

1. …funding **in** something

> - *Once upon a time, tech entrepreneurs would forage for **funding in** Silicon Valley.*
> - *Tutunjian said they are working to obtain **funding in** the proposed county budget*
> - *It's this web among CWU programs that makes **funding in** the athletic department essential, Gaudino said.*
> - *That said, I'm not against concentrating research **funding in** centres of excellence in principle.*
> - *Does this influence the government when it comes to **funding** research **in** any of the non-Russell Group universities?*

2. …funding **on** something

> - *I was disappointed to hear that the Government has cut **funding on** school sports*
> - *Previously some of the album **funding** had to be spent **on** promotion and marketing.*
> - *Countries with malaria problems definitely need to increase **funding on** malaria*
> - *The EU spent two thirds of its energy research **funding on** nuclear technologies in 2011*

3. …funding **for** something

> - *Congress is debating reductions in **funding for** the Conservation Reserve Program.*
> - *If the charges stick, the PRI risks losing federal **funding for** party activities.*
> - *In return for his support, Specter, who has Hodgkin's disease, won a large increase in cancer research **funding for** the National Institutes of Health*
> - He could also repeal limits on federal **funding for** embryonic stem cell research
> - ***Funding*** could be used **for** a number of projects identified by the Virginia Department of Transportation, such as widening Route 1 and improving key interstate exit ramps and local intersections.

Comment: Hello, Mari-Lou. May I suggest 'in' takes a prepositional object describing a geographic area / institution / department // fund; 'on' an object  referencing something to be (hopefully) improved /  developed / tackled, and 'for' either (not the 'tackled' sub-sense; 'funding for malaria' is not so good) (?)